# Asp.net core 3.1 iis worker crashes on startup

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

an asp.net core 3.1 web api crashes on startup with the following error in the event log:

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899135
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3659, time stamp: 0x5e914092

The worker won't even start. This app is published through an installer, so everything is set up automatically. It is tested and works on more than 20 server environments of Windows Server 2012, 2016, and 2019. The faulty environment runs on Windows Server 2016 with all the latest updates installed and the latest release of .net core runtime libraries.

My question is how to trace this error on is.

**Update**

After using the Debug Diagnostic Tool to collect a dump file from the application pool I followed the stack trace and it seems that asp core is trying to start a redirection that fails. Here is the full stack trace:

```
[0x0]   ucrtbase!_invoke_watson + 0x12   
[0x1]   ucrtbase!_invalid_parameter + 0x75   
[0x2]   ucrtbase!_invalid_parameter_noinfo + 0xb   
[0x3]   ucrtbase!_fileno + 0x308a1   
[0x4]   aspnetcorev2!StdWrapper::StartRedirection + 0x39   
[0x5]   aspnetcorev2!StandardStreamRedirection::Start + 0x13e   
[0x6]   aspnetcorev2!StandardStreamRedirection::TryStartRedirection + 0x35   
[0x7]   aspnetcorev2!StandardStreamRedirection::{ctor} + 0x46   
[0x8]   aspnetcorev2!HandlerResolver::FindNativeAssemblyFromHostfxr + 0x233   
[0x9]   aspnetcorev2!HandlerResolver::LoadRequestHandlerAssembly + 0x369   
[0xa]   aspnetcorev2!HandlerResolver::GetApplicationFactory + 0x3d6   
[0xb]   aspnetcorev2!APPLICATION_INFO::TryCreateApplication + 0x2e8   
[0xc]   aspnetcorev2!APPLICATION_INFO::CreateApplication + 0x25a   
[0xd]   aspnetcorev2!APPLICATION_INFO::CreateHandler + 0x1b3   
[0xe]   aspnetcorev2!ASPNET_CORE_PROXY_MODULE::OnExecuteRequestHandler + 0x108   
[0xf]   iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::RequestDoWork + 0x2e3   
[0x10]   iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModulesInternal + 0x4af   
[0x11]   iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModules + 0x2b   
[0x12]   iiscore!NOTIFICATION_MAIN::DoStateRequestExecuteHandler + 0x40   
[0x13]   iiscore!NOTIFICATION_MAIN::DoWork + 0x116   
[0x14]   iiscore!W3_CONTEXT_BASE::StartNotificationLoop + 0x93   
[0x15]   iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::OnNewRequest + 0xbf   
[0x16]   w3dt!UL_NATIVE_REQUEST::DoWork + 0xb0   
[0x17]   w3dt!UL_RECEIVE_CONTEXT::DoWork + 0x1b   
[0x18]   w3dt!WP_CONTEXT::OnCompletion + 0x3a   
[0x19]   w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread + 0xb0   
[0x1a]   w3tp!THREAD_POOL_DATA::ThreadPoolThread + 0x2b   
[0x1b]   w3tp!THREAD_MANAGER::ThreadManagerThread + 0x67   
[0x1c]   kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x24   
[0x1d]   ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart + 0x2f   
[0x1e]   ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1b
```

Is there any other information in the dump file to look for?
Still stuck with this one.

Comment: Look for any log messages from IIS in Windows Event Viewer on that web server. There is some unhandled exception occurring in your web app and hence it crashes the host process w3wp.exe. Look for any missing configuration files or settings, folder permissions, db connection, etc.,

Comment: The only error in the Event Viewer is the one I mentioned. The configuration file is not missing any elements and it is identical to other successful setups.

Comment: You have to look hard, if you go with the mindset everything is installed, configured exactly as the other 20 servers, then you will not find the issue.

Comment: Try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you samwu, this is what I did it is not clear to me what the problem is. I am following the stack and it seems that at some point asp core app is invoking a redirection that fails. The failure happens at the ucrtbase library but it is unclear to me whether this is the actual error or if there is another error earlier.

Comment: The last parts of the stack are as follows: [0x0]   ucrtbase!_invoke_watson + 0x12   
[0x1]   ucrtbase!_invalid_parameter + 0x75   
[0x2]   ucrtbase!_invalid_parameter_noinfo + 0xb   
[0x3]   ucrtbase!_fileno + 0x308a1   
[0x4]   aspnetcorev2!StdWrapper::StartRedirection + 0x39   
[0x5]   aspnetcorev2!StandardStreamRedirection::Start + 0x13e   
[0x6]   aspnetcorev2!StandardStreamRedirection::TryStartRedirection + 0x35   
[0x7]   aspnetcorev2!StandardStreamRedirection::{ctor} + 0x46   
[0x8]   aspnetcorev2!HandlerResolver::FindNativeAssemblyFromHostfxr + 0x233

Comment: The problem cannot be analyzed based on this information, you can refer to this link to analyze the dump file: [Step 6: Analyze the dump file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-a-process-in-iis-636559d3-2f31-71eb-d2ba-75da26ece9d7). but I suggest you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com) for this, because it's a very complicated process.